# Behavior when closing a user's own question as a duplicate when they have a dupe hammer

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

If a user marks one of their own questions as a duplicate, and they have a gold badge in one of the tags, is the question dupe hammered or still closed by the OP + Community user?

Comment: You can try. :P

Comment: @Tushar I don't have a dupe hammer.

Comment: I know it's not technically a duplicate but the answer is given there

Comment: @TylerH I don't see any answer to this question there.

Comment: @Servy The answer is that the Community user only appears as the question closer if the user clicks the "That works for me" button given after someone else marks it as a duplicate, as detailed in the answers. If there's no existing votes, a dupehammer would just close the question and list the user as having a gold badge in that tag.

Comment: @TylerH The other question doesn't state what you said in your last sentence, and that's what this quesiton is asking.

Comment: @Servy It's implicit (also I recall from memory seeing Boltclock or someone self-close one of their questions w/ Mjolnir and only seeing themselves as a CVer)

Comment: @TylerH How is it implied?  All it says is that you can immediately close your own question *without* a dupe hammer, if there is an existing close vote, and that all users don't have the ability to instantly close their own questions if there isn't an existing dupe vote.  That doesn't imply what you say it does.

Comment: @Servy You're right, I meant inferred, not implied, which was possible due to my previous knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is dupe-hammered without Community being bothered, as can be seen [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236367/how-many-messages-can-i-star-is-there-any-rate-limiting).

[image]

Which totally makes sense. The Gold badge holder doesn't need a user with privileges to instant duplicate close a question.